# Noticed an outdated instruction in Tor documentation site, how to correct it?

Tags: configuration, linux, ubuntu, debian, website

While browsing in Tor documentation site for instructions on getting latest `tor` for *Ubuntu 16.04*, I came across [this](https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian) site.  In there I found this command,

```
gpg --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv 886DDD89
```

But executing above command on my computer gave me following error,

```
$ gpg --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv 886DDD89
gpg: requesting key 886DDD89 from hkp server keys.gnupg.net
?: keys.gnupg.net: Host not found
gpgkeys: HTTP fetch error 7: couldn't connect: Success
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
gpg: keyserver communications error: keyserver unreachable
gpg: keyserver communications error: public key not found
gpg: keyserver receive failed: public key not found
```

Then I tried to open **keys.gnupg.net** but was redirected to [pgp.key-server.io](http://pgp.key-server.io/).  So I think **keys.gnupg.net** no longer exists.

Being in Ubuntu, I replaced **keys.gnupg.net** with **keyserver.ubuntu.com** and the command ran succesfully.  So I think **keys.gnupg.net** should be replaced with either **pgp.key-server.io** or **keyserver.ubuntu.com**.  Can anyone tell me who should I contact to do this?

Thanks

Comment: `?: keys.gnupg.net: Host not found` looks like a DNS failure to me, FWIW. What does `host keys.gnupg.net` show?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Contact](https://www.torproject.org/about/contact.html.en) page.

Your best bet would probably either be the IRC channel, or to Tweet them.

Comment: I did a chat in IRC channel and told about my query.  There two members told me that the document site's gpg command is working for them.  But for my computer, it always gives output as in my question.

Answer (score 0):

You're experiencing a censorship issue, pehaps: http://keys.gnupg.net/ opens fine for me and :

```
# gpg --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv 886DDD89
gpg: directory `/root/.gnupg' created
gpg: new configuration file `/root/.gnupg/gpg.conf' created
gpg: WARNING: options in `/root/.gnupg/gpg.conf' are not yet active during this run
gpg: keyring `/root/.gnupg/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/root/.gnupg/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key 886DDD89 from hkp server keys.gnupg.net
gpg: /root/.gnupg/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key 886DDD89: public key "deb.torproject.org archive signing key" imported
gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
```